# Visual Studio Team Services opens an empty/unupdated solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We're trying to work together on our project, using VS Team Services. The problem is when we're opening the project from within its' VSTS website - what we see is the project empty and not updated with any recent changes. 
The project's repo is on my PC, so I'm able to open it not from its' website.
'Sync' was being used.

edit: It seems that whenever I commit changes the VSTS saves our project to its' VS-site. why is that necessary?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the "commits" tab from source control?

Comment: What do you mean VS-O website? Do you mean Code > Files tab of your visual studio team services? Do you select correct Repository?

Comment: I mean I cant open the solution with VS software, using the VSTS 'Open in Visual Studio' option. The project is seen in the Code->Files tab. And I'm sorry MrHinsh, what do you mean by source control?

Comment: Does the branch you selected in VSTS website have been checked out to your PC?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Yep, pretty sure.

Comment: What version control system you used? Git or Team Foundation Version Control? If you are using Git, try to update your code with fetch and pull (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/pulling). If you are using TFVC, try to get latest version (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/download-get-files-from-server)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the source files to source control first. Then you could use Push with Git (or Check-in for TFVC) effectively. In your case, you should use the "Add to Source Control" option on the Solution itself to add all the appropriate files to source control.

Note that VSTS host two different source control technologies: Git and TFVC. 
I would advice you to understand which technology you are currently using by reading this [detailed article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc), then you will be able to add the source and work with team on the same repository.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try it [we're using Git btw]. Anyways, it seems that VSTS saves the projects just if I'm committing changes for some reason.

Comment: With Git, a commit operation is a local operation on your disk, VSTS is not involved in a Git commit. Only a Push operation would involve VSTS, as the repository will be written to. What do you exactly mean with "VSTS saves the projects just if i'm committing"?

Comment: VSTF saves the project *online* too if I commit Changes before I sync. :)

Comment: yes, that how Git works: add, commit, push, and you saved your data on the repository. Note that when using the Team Explorer of Visual Studio, when you use Commit All, then it does an implicit "Add" before the "Commit". And when you Sync, it does a Pull and then a Push. Hence your Commit+Sync equals to Add+Commit+Pull+Push. I mean, you have done that Add operation I told you :)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what we've been doing :)